# How to make remote selenium driver write driver logs to filesystem

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-remotedriver, selenium-docker

I am using a Docker Selenium Grid running on a remote machine. I am using a docker-compose to kick this off. I want to be able to have it write all the driver logs to its filesystem. I can see from the Selenium docs:

> All output gets sent to stdout, so it can be inspected by running:
>
> $ docker logs -f <container-id|container-name>
>
> You can increase the log output by passing environment variable to the containers:
>
> SE_OPTS="--log-level FINE"

I believe this is referring to the driver logs being sent to stdout. However this isn't what I want. How can I have it write all the driver logs to the filesystem?